# move object downwards with Vector2.MoveTowards in a void

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, void

So, im having a bit of a problem with this code:

```
private void ReDeal()
{
    if (!userInput.first)
    {
        userInput.FirstSelected(GameObject.Find(bottoms[0][0]));
        bottoms[0].Remove(userInput.slot1.name);
        GameObject cardToDestroy = GameObject.Find(userInput.slot1.name);

        //Move card down before destroy

        Destroy(cardToDestroy);



        bottoms[0].Add(deck.Last<string>());
        deck.RemoveAt(deck.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Currently it is working like supposed to be and the GameObject (cardToDestroy) is destroyed. What id like to do is to move the Gameobject down by its Y axis so it "slides" off the screen and destroy it after that. Tried to achieve this with a while loop and Vector2.MoveTowards or Vector2.Lerp but without success. I dont seem to get the MoveTowards working inside VOID

Comment: You can use velocity to move it down and check if it is touching ground to destroy it when its under the ground

Answer (score 0):

okay, i actually solved this one, I created an IEnumerator with while loop:

```
IEnumerator MoveCard(GameObject card, int cardIndex)
{
    Vector2 startPosition = card.transform.position;
    Vector3 stopPOsition = new Vector2(startPosition.x, startPosition.y - 4);
    while(Vector2.Distance(card.transform.position, stopPOsition) > 0.1f)
    {
        float step = 10f * Time.deltaTime;
        card.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(card.transform.position, stopPOsition, step);
        yield return null;
    }

    Destroy(card);


}
```

And then i call that IEnumerator as Coroutine inside the ReDeal() void:

```
private void ReDeal()
{
    if (!userInput.first)
    {
        userInput.FirstSelected(GameObject.Find(bottoms[0][0]));
        bottoms[0].Remove(userInput.slot1.name);
        GameObject cardToDestroy = GameObject.Find(userInput.slot1.name);

        StartCoroutine(MoveCard(cardToDestroy, 0));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this effect by using a coroutine.

```
private void ReDeal()
{
    if (!userInput.first)
        {
            userInput.FirstSelected(GameObject.Find(bottoms[0][0]));
            bottoms[0].Remove(userInput.slot1.name);
            GameObject cardToDestroy = GameObject.Find(userInput.slot1.name);
        //Move card down before destroy
        StartCoroutine(Destroy());

        bottoms[0].Add(deck.Last<string>());
        deck.RemoveAt(deck.Count - 1);
    }
}

private float movementFactor = 1.0f;
private float maximumDistance = 15f;        

private IEnumerator Destroy(GameObject go, float distance)
        {
            float accumulatedDistance = 0;
            float go_x = go.transform.position.x;
            float go_z = go.transform.position.z;
            if (accumulatedDistance < distance)
            {
                go.transform.position -= new Vector3(0,movementFactor,0);
                yield return null;
            }

        Destroy(go);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kinda thing, your best friends are Coroutines.

```
IEnumerator SlideAndDestroy(Card cardToDestroy)
{
    float velocity = -1;
    while(transform.position.y > offscreenDistance)
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(0, velocity * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.deltaTime);
    }
    Destroy(cardToDestroy);
    yield return null;
}
```

then where you want to destroy your card

```
StartCoroutine(SlideAndDestroy(cardToDestroy));
```